Polygon segmentation of branches
Let's say I have a polygon defined by a closed curve that has a semi-dendritic shape. Is it possible to partition it and extract branches and the main stem in MMA automatically?
I have been thinking about triangulation and trying to select and subset triangles of various sizes, but I don't think that works because there could be narrow parts in the main stem and wider parts in branches in general.
See the following data as and figure as an example input:
Sample Data

Following the comment below I used PolygonDecomposition on a small part of data:
pol = Polygon[{{34.26412447`, 16.99892179`}, {34.12581321`, 
     17.08790256`}, {34.06258573`, 17.11001673`}, {34.01613721`, 
     17.13985274`}, {34.01385453`, 17.14493958`}, {34.04124152`, 
     17.13443953`}, {34.05939596`, 17.11704654`}, {34.08575133`, 
     17.10709463`}, {34.10923695`, 17.11639593`}, {34.12694564`, 
     17.12896975`}, {34.13867404`, 17.15561644`}, {34.1525918`, 
     17.16437812`}, {34.15455269`, 17.19409817`}, {34.18012412`, 
     17.22`}, {34.1876688`, 17.23192036`}, {34.18823524`, 
     17.21435227`}, {34.15808795`, 17.19168238`}, {34.15958615`, 
     17.16457678`}, {34.13832859`, 17.15100245`}, {34.12865697`, 
     17.12326678`}, {34.10924756`, 17.10539255`}, {34.27211293`, 
     17.00997544`}, {34.2925131`, 17.00270058`}}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], PolygonDecomposition[pol, "Convex"]}]

But it not quite right at this level, and there is no way to distinguish between the polygons of branches:

Interestingly, if the data is much simpler, @syed 's suggestion works for example for :
pol2 = Polygon[{{0, 0}, {0, 8}, {-4, 8}, {-4, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 
    14}, {2, 14}, {2, 9}, {4, 9}, {4, 8}, {2, 8}, {2, 2}, {10, 
    2}, {10, 0}, {2, 0}, {2, -5}, {0, -5}, {0, 0}}]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[White], PolygonDecomposition[pol2, "Convex"]}]

But the PolygonDecomposition doesn't work for more complicated data apparently.

Have you looked at PolygonDecomposition? For example: PolygonDecomposition[Polygon@data, "Convex"] // Graphics

Thanks @Syed, it doesn't quite do it right. Maybe it can be used somehow but I can't think of it right now. Please see the edits.

The other thing I tried was : poly = Polygon@data;, x = poly // Graphics // ColorNegate // Thinning // Binarize //    ColorReplace[#, White -> Red] & and poly // Graphics // ColorNegate // Thinning // Binarize //     MorphologicalBranchPoints // Dilation[#, DiskMatrix[3]] & //   ImageAdd[#, x] &

Can you please take a look at SkeletonTransform? For example: SkeletonTransform[Graphics[{White, pol}, Background -> Black]]

An attempt: cst = FindClusters[data, 6, Method -> "SpanningTree"]; and Graphics[{Polygon /@ cst}]. If I could only split the dendrite at the morphological branch points ...

Skeletonization and other rasterized image processing, including clustering, dilation etc may somehow be used indirectly, but their direct output won't be the exact polygon coordinates, right? Maybe for example the image processing output will define the partition boundaries and then I can divide the polygons based on those boundaries. But the result can't be direct output from these morphological operations unless I am wrong and the exact data can be recovered.

Last one: cgc = poly // Graphics // ColorNegate // Binarize // ImageAdjust //      MorphologicalGraph[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] & //     ConnectedGraphComponents // First and tree = cgc // TreePlot[#, VertexLabels -> "Name"] &. Getting information to flow between a geometric figure/graphics/image/graph would solve various problems.

Nice, this gives a good structure for the hierarchy.
